# Spring 3.0.3 SAXParseException with mvc:resources

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

my question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896885/spring-3-1-1-saxparseexception-with-mvcresources). Nevertheless, I cannot find the mistake :-(

Here is my myapp-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.myapp.controller" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have checked the xml several times, even the answer mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896885/spring-3-1-1-saxparseexception-with-mvcresources) question. I still get `Line 15 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a version > 3.0.3, because this feature is available since version 3.0.4! I tried the explanation referenced in my question with version 3.2. and it works perfectly!